# Android - weird problem with CheckBoxes in custom listview adapters?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I am having a weird problem.

I am working on a app which has one button and a listview with checkbox(one per list item) and functionality required that whenever i click on this button, checked items from list should be removed. I saved the state of checkbox in my custom ListView Adapter using Boolean type Arraylist and trying to access it in my main activity but the problem is whenever i click on Button its not removing the checked items instead its removing the items of exact amount as checked items from the bottom of the List.

here is my custom adapter's code -

```
public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Activity activity;
private Object[] data;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listItems;
public static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private PackageManager pm;
public ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private ArrayList<String> itemSelected = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<TextView> ctv = new ArrayList<TextView>();
private int posi;
private String pkg;

public IconAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items)
{
    activity = a;
    listItems = items;
    data = items.toArray();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    pm = a.getPackageManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        itemChecked.add(i,false);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        itemSelected.add(i," ");
    }

}

public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public CheckBox checkBox;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(row==null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    String s = data[position].toString();
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");
    String[] mToken = tokens[0].split("=");
    String taskName = mToken[1];
    String[] mTokens = tokens[1].split("=");
    final String pkgName =  mTokens[1].substring(0, (mTokens[1].length() - 1));


    holder.textView.setText(taskName);
    holder.textView.setTag(pkgName);


    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean b) {

                    if (b)
                    {
                        itemChecked.set(position, true);
                        itemSelected.set(position, pkgName);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemChecked.set(position, false);


                    }


        }
    });

    holder.checkBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position));


    try{
        Drawable icon =   pm.getApplicationIcon(pkgName);
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ne)
    {

    }

     return row;
}




public String getPkgName(int position)
{
    return itemSelected.get(position);
}
public void setItemChecked(boolean isChecked)
{

}
}
```

nd here is my onClick code -

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    int size = icon.getCount();
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(icon.itemChecked.get(i))
        {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
    icon.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and it also giving me an IOOBException sometime.

Please help.

Comment: Is that an Out-Of-Body-Exception? :D

Comment: @Rajath No that is an IndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClick` code is wrong, because after `list.remove(i)` you got `size = size-1`, but you still assume that it's constant. You need to rewrite your delete loop. Plus you have to realize that, when you do `remove` and do nothing with your iteration index `i`, you skip 1 item (the one that was situated right after removed one).

Comment: for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)

i rewrite it and IOOBException is not there any more but what about removing items from bottom???? that is still my main error. any idea? solution?

Comment: Just a guess: try to move `icon.notifyDataSetChanged();` from the loop: `for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(icon.itemChecked.get(i))
        {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    } icon.notifyDataSetChanged();`
It could invoke `getView` that will reset your `onCheckedChangeListener` with new position that could cause a conflict.

Comment: @user639183 na it wont work either coz before you advised i was doing the same so for just debugging purpose i put it inside the loop. :(